# Order this array by date modified?

Tags: php, usort, filemtime

I have a php file that is creating a array of everything in my users directory, the array is then being sent back to a iPhone.

The array that my php is creating is ordering them alphabetically, i want it to sort by the date the file was created..

Here is what my php file looks like

```
<?php
$username = $_GET['username'];
$path = "$username/default/";


$files = glob("{$path}/{*.jpg,*.jpeg,*.png}", GLOB_BRACE);

// output to json
echo json_encode($files);

?>
```

How would i do this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [`usort()`](http://www.php.net/manual/function.usort.php) with a callback which calls `filemtime()`...

This is untested, but I believe it will set you on the correct path...

```
// First define a comparison function to be used as a callback
function filetime_callback($a, $b)
{
  if (filemtime($a) === filemtime($b)) return 0;
  return filemtime($a) < filemtime($b) ? -1 : 1; 
}

// Then sort with usort()
usort($files, "filetime_callback");
```

This should sort them oldest-first. If you want them newest-first, change `<` to `>` in the callback `return` ternary operation.

Comment: I needed to add $dirPath:  global $dirPath;
  if (filemtime($dirPath . $a) == filemtime($dirPath . $b)) . . .

Comment: Simply and the best answer! Works as wanted! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As Michael Berkowski mentioned, using `usort()` is the way to go, but if this is a one-off sorting (i.e. you only need to sort an array this way once in your code), you can use an anonymous function:

```
usort($files, function ($a, $b){
    if (filemtime($a) === filemtime($b)) return 0;
    return filemtime($a) < filemtime($b) ? -1 : 1; 
});
```

While not necessary, it does save a function call.

If you need to sort files this way more than once, creating a separate named function is preferable.